# Template-based email Litmus preview showing only a text list of content blocks

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, email-template

The email shows fine when I send a preview to my email clients, but when I preview it in the Salesforce Litmus tab, I just get a list of AMPScript content blocks that look like:

```
%%=ContentBlockbyID("234656")=%%
%%=ContentBlockbyID("234004")=%%
%%=ContentBlockbyID("435645")=%%
%%=ContentBlockbyID("567865")=%%
%%=ContentBlockbyID("123423")=%%
%%=ContentBlockbyID("678566")=%%
```

Screenshot:

[image]

I'm new to Salesforce, Litmus, and HTML emails in general. I don't know where to begin looking in to this problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you preview in Litmus tab, can you ensure that you select a data in "Subscriber Preview and Attributes" section and let the email render?

[image]